# Is there the "Only use Tab or Enter to commit" option in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there the "Only use Tab or Enter to commit" option in Visual Studio Code?

If yes, how to uncheck this option?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After browsing the default keybindings.json file, I think we can configure this.

First, bring up the key bindings settings file from File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

Then on the right hand side, paste the following code:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "shift+9", // (
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+0", // )
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+,", // <
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+.", // >
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "[",
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "]",
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "space",
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": ",",
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+;", // :
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+/", // ?
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": ";",
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "=",
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "numpad_add", // + 
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+=", // + 
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+8", // *
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "numpad_multiply", // *
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "-", // -
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "numpad_subtract", // -
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "/", // /
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "numpad_divide", // /
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+7", // &
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+\\", // |
        "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey"
    }
]
```

Save the file and the key bindings should be in effect immediately.

You can add more commit characters if you wish, just follow the pattern.

Comment: Is there any way to accept the suggestion *and* print the typed character 'key'? I tried `"command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion && type"` and an additional parameter `"args": {"text":"/"}` for the type command, but that command isn't being accepted. Both `acceptSelectedSuggestion` and `type` commands work correctly individually.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware at the time of this writing, Visual Studio Code does not have this option, sorry.