# VS code autocompletion customization - do not automatically select any suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I would like to customize VScode autocompletion behaviour to suit my liking.

Namely:

1. When the suggestions list appears, I don't want any suggestion to be selected.
2. When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd>, I want to cycle through the suggestions (thus selecting one). <kbd>Esc</kbd> should unselect any selected suggestion (and can close the suggestions list, optionally).
3. When a suggestion is selected, any character should accept that suggestion (so edit my code with the text of that suggestion).

Item 2. is achieved by editing the keybinds.

I haven't found a way to get the behaviour of item 1.

For item 3., a dirty hack could be to exploit the `editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter` setting, and using all characters as commit characters, but I haven't found how to edit which characters are commit characters.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour using the settings?

If not, is there an extension that provides this behaviour?

Ideally, I would like to avoid coding my own extension, but I could resort to that if no other solution is available.

Note: this question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349897/is-there-anyway-to-configure-vscode-to-not-select-the-first-item-from-the-sugges), because I do not want to press <kbd>Return</kbd> to accept a suggestion (unless i want to accept the suggestion *and* insert a new line).

edit: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36739459/2451259) can implement item 3 using the dirty hack described above, I just have to copy the same keybind for all possible characters with the same "when" conditions, now I just need to find a way to get item 1. (and ideally find a better way to get item 3.).

edit again: to make my question clearer, I've recorded the desired behaviour from vim, with the keys pressed.
[image: desired behaviour as experienced in vim]

Comment: As an addition to item 3, is there any way to accept the suggestion *and* print the typed character? I tried `"command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion && type"` and an additional parameter `"args": {"text":"/"}` for the type command, but that command isn't being accepted. Both `acceptSelectedSuggestion` and `type` commands work correctly individually.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new approach to how suggestions are handled coming in vscode v1.75, see [Implement "Suggestion Mode" from Visual Studio](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139825).  New setting:

```
Editor > Suggest: Selection Mode
```

> Controls whether a suggestion is selected when the widget shows.  Note
> that this only applies to automatically triggered suggestions
> (`Editor: QUick Suggestions` and `Editor: Suggest on Trigger Characters`) and that a suggestion is always selected when explicitly
> invoked, e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Options:

1. `always` Always select a suggestion when automatically Intellisense
2. `never` Never Always select a suggestion when automatically Intellisense
3. `whenTriggerCharacter` Select a suggestion only when triggering Intellisemse from a trigger character
4. `whenQuickSuggestion` Select a suggestion only when triggering Intellisense as you type

Demo 1: modes `never` and `always` - note that with `never` there is no selected item in the suggestion box and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> a newline is inserted into the code.  Option `always` has a selected suggestion item automatically and <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects and inserts that.

[image: suggestionMode: whenTriggerCharacter]

Demo2: mode `whenTriggerCharacter`, note that although suggestions are shown none are selected and I can <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> and they are inserted.  Only when a trigger character like `.` is entered is a suggestion **selected** and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert that selected suggestion item into the code (depending on your setting regarding using Enter as a suggestion completion).

[image: suggestion modes: always and never]

Demo3: mode `whenQuickSuggestion` You will get **selected** suggestions as you type, except for trigger characters.  Trigger characters will still show suggestions but none will be selected so you can <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

- Note that in all cases above where there are suggestions shown but none are selected the <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> and <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> keys will scroll and select items in the suggestions.

There is another demo at the link above: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139825#issuecomment-1364056148

Answer (score 1):

For item 1, you could press the up-arrow key de-select a suggestion.
or you could go to VSC, From Visual Studio, select “Tools” > “Options“.
Select “Text Editor” in the left pane.
Select the language you are using (C#, C++, Basic, etc.).
For C# and Basic, choose “IntelliSense“. ...
For C# and Basic, check the “Show completion list after a character is typed” to disable it.
For the 3rd item, you could just not write any parenthesis, < or >, { or }, [ or ], or < and >.
instead, just write what's inside of these. And the auto completion will put every sign in it's right place.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for the same. But the closest I came was to preview the suggestion, which I turned on: Put this in your `settings.json` in VScode

```
"editor.suggest.preview": true
```

But I don't think the actual insert feature is available in VScode yet.

Answer (score 0):

for item 2:

first you will need to disable selecting a suggestion with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. for that, change the keybinding for  `"insertSnippet"`

```
  {
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && hasSnippetCompletions && !editorTabMovesFocus && !inSnippetMode"
  },
```

then, to add navigation with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd> modify `"selectNextSuggestion"` and `"selectPrevSuggestion"`

*make sure that both shortcuts have `"when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"`

```
  {
    "key": "down",
    "command": "-selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+tab",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
```

for exiting the snippet selection <kbd>Esc</kbd> should alredy be the default key. If that's not the case, modify the `"leaveSnippet"` keybinding.

```
  {
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "leaveSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && inSnippetMode"
  },
```